# Sportbike Throttle Body Out of Sync

Tags: motorcycle, yamaha, throttle-body

I recently purchased a 2017 R6.  At around ~450 miles I had the 600 mile maintenance done early because I noticed my bike wasn't shifting as smoothly and the engine wasn't running as smoothly (running junk).  In that maintenance I had the oil changed and the throttle bodies synced and I noticed it was running as smooth as when it was new.  A few days later I noticed that it was already running pretty rough, and now at around the 900 mile mark it's running just like how it was at 450 miles.  I suspect that the throttle bodies are already out of sync.

Is this something I am doing wrong, or is this something I should take up with warranty?  Is it because I had the throttle bodies synced too early and during the break in period?  Any ideas as to why this is happening?  I do tend to ride fairly rough for short distances but I keep my RPMs below 8000.

Comment: I'm thinking one of two things is happening: 1) the break-in is happening which is causing the TB's to become out of sync; 2) something in the TB's isn't staying put (self adjusting). The second seems more probable, but I'm not a motorcycle person, so just spit-balling at this point.

Comment: If its under warranty id be taking it straight back to the dealer. A new bike with such low mileage should not be running rough at all. Make sure they acknowlege the issue and address it while its under warranty. Odd thought.. is there any chance you've got dirty fuel?

Comment: I'm not really sure but TB's are not self adjusting for motorcycles.  And I would really like to avoid taking it to the dealership, the ones in my area aren't exactly known to be...reliable.  I always fill up with the highest grade Texaco/Chevron fuel.